# Are the final events of DBZ considered canon?

Tags: dragon-ball, dragon-ball-z, dragonball-super

In Dragon Ball Z, the series flashes forward 10 years after the defeat of Buu and we're introduced to things like Gohan and Videl's daughter Pan, lazy teenage versions of Trunks and Goten, and a reincarnated Buu (Uub).

Since Dragon Ball Super begins sometime shortly after the defeat of Buu, are the flash forward events of DBZ wiped from canon, similar to the GT history?

My biggest point of confusion is the fact that Pan is 4 in the final events of DBZ which means she was born 6 years after Goku kills Buu. But at the beginning of Dragon Ball Super, Gohan and Videl announce they're pregnant with Pan. This could be explained easily if Super picked up some 5 years after Buu's defeat but Goten and Trunks appear to be the same age as they were in Z. So it seems likely that Pan is born way earlier than 6 years after Buu's defeat.

Do these events reconcile or was the end of Z undone to make room for Super to tell new stories?